# Android application works on emulator and via USB debugging on device, but not on device standalone

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator, usb

I am writing an application that connects to a web service in a background thread and displays the service response in the foreground activity. The app works as intended both in the emulator and on my phone via USB debugging. However, when I export the app through Eclipse, then install it on the device, it crashes with an "App is not responding. Would you like to close it?" notification.

I have two activities - a main activity with a button, which navigates to the second activity. The second activity creates a `ServiceIntent`, runs it and displays the result when the service call is complete.

My main trouble here is that the app fails when there is no possibility to actually debug it. I would highly appreciate it if you could point me in any direction here! Have you had this problem before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you see the output of `adb logcat` or does this also interfere with reproducing the bug? I'm pretty sure that `logcat` will show you the last N log entries, so you don't need to be debugging the app to capture that output: for instance you can run the app not connected via USB, reproduce the crash, plug it in, run `adb logcat` and you'll see the output from during the crash.

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly. I could see that it is freezing upon the service call.The reason for that was an `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` in my code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem - it was an `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` inside the `onCreate()` of the service. It was making the app freeze on the device standalone, but run perfectly while USB debugging. Thank you for the help [spacemanaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352061/spacemanaki)!